# How to put setAdapter in static method and access it from another class

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a ListView in which i am settingAdapter onCreate. But I want put setAdapter in a static method and invoke it in onClick of a button in another class. Can this be possible ? Right now it says "Cannot make static reference to a non-static setAdapter method". Below is my code : i have mentioned in code which part i am looking to have it in my static method "addItems()". Suggestions welcome. Thanks in advance

```
public class LogListView extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static String newString;
    private static EntryAdapter adapter;
    int clickCounter = 0;
    static ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    static SharedPreferences preferences = null;  
    private static Context context = null;
    StringTokenizer tokens;
    String first;
    String second;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        /*I WANT THIS LOOP TO BE IN  "ADDITEMS() METHOD*/
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("LOG", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        newString = preferences.getString("log", "");

        //items.add(new SectionItem("Log Report"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("", newString));

        adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        /*I WANT THIS LOOP TO BE IN  "ADDITEMS() METHOD ENDS*/


    }

    //Method which will handle dynamic insertion
    public static void addItems() {
        items.add(new EntryItem("", newString));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    //Method which will handle dynamic insertion ends

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        if(!items.get(position).isSection()) {

            EntryItem item = (EntryItem)items.get(position);
            //Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + item.title , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + position , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        if (position == 9){

        }

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you need such static method in ListActivity than you have to redesign your app code ...

Comment: Will the other `Activity` be created after this one and is there only 1 instance of this `Activity`?

Comment: why u need to update adapter from other activity?

Comment: @Anil - Because the Button Click is in that Activity

Comment: rather than updating from other Activity, try for updating in onResume of first activity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. There is not need to setAdapter in static method. What I can do is onCreate i can setAdapter and keep it aside. And onClick i can enter values using

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```